# Admin page repeatable fields

Tags: admin-menu, options

I have a submenu page set up and I want to add repeatable fields to it.

The submenu page is to add staff holidays (fields will be Start Date, End Date and a multi select to pick the staff members name). Setting up the first lot of fields is not a problem, however, I want a button that each time I click it, it will another set of the above mentioned fields.

I'm aware there will be some Javascript involved and have googled this a few times, but cannot find what I want.

Can somebody help please?

Comment: I'd look at Advanced Custom Fields Pro, which includes a repeater field type. It sounds like it'll handle all of that for you.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to mention that I don't want to use ACF as it's a self-contained plugin that I'm building. But yes, ACF would be an ideal solution had this have not been the case.

Comment: Ok, in that case, why not look at how ACF does it and learn from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

and use array so input should be something like this

```
<input type="text" name="data[1][time][start]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][time][end]">

<input type="text" name="data[2][time][start]">
<input type="text" name="data[2][time][end]">
```

....

then save data as array

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'field_name', $_POST['data']);
```